# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using memcpy()

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am facing segmentation fault when I'm doing memcpy():

```
 case 32:
        std::cout<<"ARVRPipe: RECEIVED_MAP_ROUTE_PACKET_RESULTS"<<std::endl;

        
        memcpy(&(mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket), inputBuffer, inputBufferSize);


        received_data.path_size = mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path_size;
        std::cout<<"Path Size  : " <<received_data.path_size<<std::endl;

        received_data.instruction_size = mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.instruction_size;
        std::cout<<"Instruction Size  : " <<received_data.instruction_size<<std::endl;


        if (mCommonMessagePtr && !mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path.empty()) {

            if (mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path.size() == received_data.path_size) {
                
                std::cout<<"Inside If condition : "<<std::endl;

                received_data.path.resize(received_data.path_size);
                size_t path_coor_size = received_data.path.size();
                std::cout<<"Size of received_data path : "<<path_coor_size<<std::endl;

                // Segmentation fault in the below line
                memcpy(received_data.path.data(), mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path.data(),  path_coor_size* sizeof(std::pair<double, double>));

                // Print out path coordinates
                for (const auto& coord : received_data.path) {
                    std::cout << "Coordinate : " << coord.first << " --- " << coord.second << std::endl;
                }
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error: Size mismatch between mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path and received_data.path_size" << std::endl;
            }

        }
```

so this `received_data` and `maproutePacket` both are object to the same structure given below:

```cpp
struct ReceivedData
{
  int path_size;
  int instruction_size;
  std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> path;
  double distance;
  std::vector<Instruction> instructions;
  double time;
};
```

when I do memcpy() it shows segmentation fault in the below line:

```
 memcpy(received_data.path.data(), mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path.data(),  path_coor_size* sizeof(std::pair<double, double>));
```

Comment: Use C++ `std::copy()`.

Comment: You can't use `std::memcpy` for almost any C++ object. It does a byte-wise copy, not an object-copy.

Comment: You also can't transfer, using files, networks, or anything else, any C++ object that might contain pointers or handles or similar. Such things are local you the currently running process only. No other process will be able to use those. I suggest you look into the subject of *serialization* if you want to transfer objects.

Comment: @273K don't even need `std::copy`, can just do `received_data.path = mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path`

Comment: Better to use an array of struct representing your path instead of a vector of pairs.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have used this ```received_data.path = mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path``` , again give ```segmentation fault```

Comment: Yes, as stated above you've already broken the data structures by sending them over a network, the memcpy crash is a symptom of the issue rather than the cause

Comment: Any suggestion how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the data type of `mCommonMessagePtr->maproutePacket.path`?

Comment: @kiner_shah ```std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>```

Comment: Better to use a simple for loop.

Comment: @kiner_shah can you tell me n little elaborate it

Comment: Please edit the question and add the backtrace of the crash.